# If acceleration $a = v\cdot\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}$ , then why isn't acceleration always zero when velocity is zero?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

We know that,

$$\begin{align}
a&=\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dt}\\[3pt]
&=\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}\cdot\frac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm dt}\\[3pt]
&=v\cdot~\frac{\mathrm dv}{\mathrm dx}
\end{align}$$

According to this equation, whenever velocity is $0$, acceleration becomes $0$ as well.

However, we know that this is not always the case.

**For example**, when we throw a ball upwards, at its maximum height, its velocity becomes $0$ but the acceleration is non-zero ($g$ downwards).

Can someone please help me understand what is wrong in my approach?

Comment: We know that, $1 + 1 = 2$. But multiplying and dividing by $0$, we get $1 + 1 = 0 * 2 / 0$. According to this equation, $1 + 1 = 0 * (\ldots) = 0$. What is wrong?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/268011/).

Comment: Think in realastic way ,if acceleration is zero ,when velocity is zero ,you will never able to reach the velocity of even 1m/s,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perhaps worth considering your equation in terms of finite changes rather than infinitesimal changes.

If $a = \dfrac {\Delta v}{\Delta t}$ then for a given interval of time $\Delta t$ there is a fixed change in the velocity $\Delta v$.

$a = \dfrac{\Delta v}{\Delta x}\dfrac{\Delta x}{\Delta t}$

If the second (velocity) term on the right hand side of the equation for acceleration  is getting smaller and smaller then $\Delta x$ must be must be getting smaller and smaller.

If $\Delta x$ is getting smaller and smaller then the first term is getting bigger and bigger.

Since the rates of increase and decrease for the two terms, which are both dependent on $\Delta x$, are the same then the product of the two terms stays constant.

Note that the first term blows up if you try and make $\Delta x$ equal to zero.

Answer (score 1):

Calculus doesn’t work that way. You can’t regroup $(dv/dv)(dv/dt)$ as you’re trying to.

The basic parts of $dv/dt$ are $v$, the velocity, and $d/dt$, an operator that forms a derivative.